# Why binding a variable to Exception types in a Scala pattern with pipes is inferred to type "Throwable"?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-inference

I have the following code excerpt in Scala:

```
case e@(_: java.text.ParseException | _: NumberFormatException | _: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) =>
```

The most specific type which is inferred for expression `e` is `Throwable` instead of `Exception`. Why is this so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug, namely [SI-8881](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8881).

Answer (score 1):

I can't really be sure as you didn't paste the full code, but I believe that the `Throwable` you are getting doesn't come from pattern matching but instead from the thing you are matching on itself; this is how I can re-create the issue:

```
scala> trait Foo
defined trait Foo

scala> trait Fox extends Foo
defined trait Fox

scala> trait Bar extends Fox
defined trait Bar

scala> trait Baz extends Fox
defined trait Baz

scala> def test(x: Foo) = x match { case e @ (_: Bar | _: Baz) => e }
test: (x: Foo)Foo
```

I believe that the problem is that when you use the `|` in pattern-matching you can't use the inference as you'd like to and so you are just getting back the type that you provided in input.